# Two way cascading Kendo dropdownlist -- Is this possible?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I have two dropdown lists that I want to interact with each other.

Lets say I have a list of people and groups they belong to.
    var personList = ['Steve', 'Billy', 'Terrence'],
        groupList = ['fun', 'work', 'part-time-alien'];

The behaviour I want is that the user can select a person and the second dropdown would populate with all the groups they belong to. However if the user selects a group first, it should give the option to select all people belonging to that group from the person dropdown.

The only examples so far that i've seen only deal with one way cascading. Is it possible to do it two way?

Ideally I would like to achieve this with only two dropdowns but other solutions I could think of were to have a couple of radio buttons above and depending which was chosen could change the configuration of the dropdowns on the fly?

Or have two pairs of dropdowns, one with the person dropdown on top, the other pair having the groups dropdown first.

Again, I'd really prefer to do this only with two dropdowns. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the built in cascade handling, just use the change event of the 2 dropdowns. e.g.:

```
var data = [
    { text: "Steve", value: "1", groups: ["1", "2"] },
    { text: "Billy", value: "2", groups: ["3"] },
    { text: "Terrence", value: "3", groups: ["2", "3"] }
];

var dataG = [
    { text: "Fun", value: "1", people: ["1"] },
    { text: "Work", value: "2", people: ["1", "3"] },
    { text: "Part Time Alien", value: "3", people: ["2", "3"] }
];

// create DropDownList from input HTML element
$("#people").kendoDropDownList({
    dataTextField: "text",
    dataValueField: "value",
    dataSource: data,
    optionLabel: "Select person...",
    change: function(e){
      var dataItem = e.sender.dataItem();                          
      var GroupList = [];
      for (i = 0; i < dataG.length; i++){
         if ($.inArray(dataG[i].value, dataItem.groups) > -1){
           GroupList.push(dataG[i]);
         }
      }
      var dropdownlist = $("#groups").data("kendoDropDownList");
      dropdownlist.setDataSource(GroupList);
    }
});

$("#groups").kendoDropDownList({
    dataTextField: "text",
    dataValueField: "value",
    dataSource: dataG,
    optionLabel: "Select group...",
    change: function(e){
      var dataItem = e.sender.dataItem();
      var PeopleList = [];
      for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
         if ($.inArray(data[i].value, dataItem.people) > -1){
           PeopleList.push(data[i]);
         }
      }
      var dropdownlist = $("#people").data("kendoDropDownList");
      dropdownlist.setDataSource(PeopleList);
    }
});
```

> **[DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/IVowu)**

Comment: Thanks that's pretty much what I need! There is a small bug if you choose a person then a group, then deselect the person, both drop down lists empty their datasource and you have to refresh to get them back.